# bash division of numbers in text file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two numbers in test.txt file, I would like a way to divide the second number by the first number and assign the result to a variable or file in a bash script that I can use. I have used `awk "NR==1" test.txt` to get number1 displayed on command line but inside of script, I have tried `awk "NR==2" test.txt / awk "NR==1" test.txt` and all of the quote / bracket combinations of such. The command line use gives num2/num1 as result, not the result of division or gives syntax error. I am using Debian Linux as OS.
 test.txt file contains

```
0250368000
0182885654
```

I want the second number divided by the first `var=0182885654/0250368000`
The numbers will change from time to time and I want a script that will process the numbers.

Comment: Can you show us the text-file with the numbers (add to question). And exactly what you have tried.

Answer (score 6):

Assign to a variable

```
var=$(awk 'NR==1{a=$0}NR==2{print $0/a}' test.txt)
```

or output to a file:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0}NR==2{print $0/a}' test.txt > output
```

Comment: result is -nan, not really correct answer

Comment: @HaroldMeneley With your example of `test.txt` file I get 0.730467. Is there anything else in the file apart of these numbers?

Comment: There is definitely something else in the file. `printf %s\\n 0250368000 0182885654 >test.txt; { cat test.txt; echo /p; } | dc` prints `1` not a *bunch of `dc stack empty` errors*. You could only get a *bunch* with a *bunch* of commands anyway.

Comment: There are two numbers only in plain text format, the first number is the large one, and the second should represent only a portion of the first. The numbers will change every day. There are no character encoding or special formatting.The problem seems to be the simple fact that the answer is less than one, not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
quotient=$(dc -f test.txt -e 'r[num desired precision]k/p')
```

Comment: bunch of dc stack empty errors and unimplemented errors

Comment: Well, that does depend on the contents of `test.txt` being only two numbers. Apparently that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an old step by step trick to obtain something that works, but would have liked to do it all in one step.

```
num1=$(awk 'NR==2' test1.txt)
echo $num1 #result is 0247421924
num2=$(awk 'NR==1' test1.txt)
echo $num2 #result is 0250368000
score=`awk 'BEGIN{printf("%0.0f", '$num1' * 100 / '$num2' )}'`

echo $score # result is 99
```

As you can see, I had to multiply the first number by 100 to get an integer. Sorry, couldn't get line spacing to work

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk ' NR == 1 { a = $1 }
       NR == 2 { b = $1 }
       END { print a
             print b
             print b/a } ' data
```

where data is a text file containing,

```
0250368000
0182885654
```

Comment: This answer actually does obtain the proper answer and I only had to add ; between prints to get it to work on the command line. Thanks.